# Linux command to find a single directory - which is the only directory present

Tags: linux

I need a command whose output would be the absolute path of the directory I am searching for.

**Condition: The parent directory should not contain any other directory except for the one I am looking for.**

Example :

Let's say I have the following directory structures and I am searching for the GHI directory :

1. /home/user/ABC/XYZ/
2. /home/user/ABC/PQR/GHI
3. /home/user/LMN/GHI/
4. /home/user/LMN/DEF/

Now, If I run the command, the output should give me:

**- /home/user/ABC/PQR/GHI** 
as GHI is the only sub directory present in the parent directory PQR.

Answer (score 1):

```
find ~ -type d -maxdepth 2 -depth 2 | awk -F/ '{print $5, $4}' \
    | sort -k2 | uniq -u -f1 | awk '{print $2"/"$1}'
```

How does it work?  First it prints all the depth-2 directories, then it flips them from `ABC/XYZ` to `XYZ ABC`.  It then takes only the unique ones, ignoring the first field (`XYZ` in our example).  Unique records are then flipped back to the original order like `ABC/XYZ`.

Note it does not properly handle directory names containing spaces.  That's an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I don't have the feeling that the OP cares about how it works. He just *needs* a command.

Comment: @hek2mgl: Absolutely.  That's why I was happy to write this shell monstrosity instead of real code!

Comment: @JohnZwinck : Modified the command as - find ./ -maxdepth 4 -type d  | awk -F/ '{print $5, $4, $3}'     | sort -k2 | uniq -u -f1 | awk '{print $2"/"$1}' . This worked for my requirement, Thanks..!!

Comment: @hek2mgl : Precisely. :-P

Comment: @hek2mgl: Check  it out--straight from the gutter into prod!